# Make horizontal lines with pandas yearly data?

Tags: python, pandas, date, horizontal-line

I have a pandas object with yearly averages data in this form:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2005-12-31', '2006-12-31', '2007-12-31', '2008-12-31',
               '2009-12-31', '2010-12-31', '2011-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-DEC')
2005-12-31    3.347463
2006-12-31    3.042220
2007-12-31    3.296574
2008-12-31    3.082333
2009-12-31    2.471380
2010-12-31    2.337974
2011-12-31    2.083004
```

I would like to draw horizontal lines from beginning of the year till the end of the year with the values currently associated to the last day of the year. Currently, when I plot this pandas object, I get linear interpolation between the points at the end of the year. I have tried adding indexes with:

```
new_index= ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008','2009', '2010', '2011']
df_year.reindex(new_index)
```

which result in the same graph. Or adding the first day of each year (not good for automation though) with:

```
z=datetime.strptime('01-01-2005', '%d-%m-%Y')
indx.append(pd.Index([z]))
df_year.set_value(z,2)
```

which result in:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2005-12-31', '2006-12-31', '2007-12-31', '2008-12-31',
               '2009-12-31', '2010-12-31', '2011-12-31', '2005-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
2005-12-31    3.347463
2006-12-31    3.042220
2007-12-31    3.296574
2008-12-31    3.082333
2009-12-31    2.471380
2010-12-31    2.337974
2011-12-31    2.083004
2005-01-01    2.000000
```

However, it seems like it cannot detect that that date is before 2005-12-31 so its just draw a horizontal line from 2005 till 2011. I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Unfortunately, I am not able to upload the graphs, since I am working on a different server and I am not able to save images.

Thank you.

**Edition:**

Here is the code I used:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df_month.index,  df_month, 'k')
plt.plot(df_year.index,  df_year, 'g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try `plot.bar` function for `DataFrame` objects?

Comment: Also, may you share the code you used for ploting your data?

Comment: Dear Cedric, I added the code. Unfortunately, since I am working on a different server I cannot share the data. But I will explain it here. It is a (12,) numpy array of yearly averaged data. I have to plot it on a monthly averaged data, so I don want to manually change things (i.e. I don think axhline is useful). Does plot.bar draw horizontal lines? Or maybe by decreasing the thickness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want a bar plot or steps like plit for you values using dates as x axis.

### DataFrame

If we set the `DataFrame`as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame([["2005-12-31", 3.347463],["2006-12-31", 3.042220],["2007-12-31", 3.296574],["2008-12-31", 3.082333],["2009-12-31", 2.471380],["2010-12-31", 2.337974],["2011-12-31", 2.083004]])
df.columns = ["date", "value"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df = df.set_index(["date"])
```

Your `DataFrame` would be:

```
>>> df
               value
date                
2005-12-31  3.347463
2006-12-31  3.042220
2007-12-31  3.296574
2008-12-31  3.082333
2009-12-31  2.471380
2010-12-31  2.337974
2011-12-31  2.083004
```

Note that we set the `date` column as index.

### Using plot.bar

You can use `plot.bar` function. If it's not available due to `pandas` version you can try `plot(kind="bar")` instead. Below code would plot and show the desired graph:

```
df.plot.bar(width=1,fill=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And the output graph would result into:
[image: Bar Plot]

Note that using `width` as 1 we get the bars with whole width. `width` by default is 0.5.

### Using plot with steps-mid as linetyle

Otherwise you can use `plot` with `steps-mid` as linestyle with below code:

```
df.plot(ls="steps-mid")
plt.show()
```

You get as graph:
[image: Plot with steps]